# Convert and extract row using mysql and regular expression pattern

Tags: mysql

How do I to extract a converted value from my db?

```
SELECT name FROM clients LIMIT 1;
```

It will list: "13's Automotors"

But I want to show "13SAUTOMOTORS", listing only letters and numbers without spaces.

> Server type: Percona Server Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona
>   Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3 Protocol version: 10

Comment: Which version of the MySQL server do you use?

Comment: Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3
Protocol version: 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions (MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10+) support the `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(name, '[^\\d\\w]', '') as converted_name
FROM clients
```

will replace all non-digit and non-word characters with an empty string.

If you need the result in uppercase, use `UPPER()`

```
SELECT upper(regexp_replace(name, '[^\\d\\w]', '')) as converted_name
FROM clients
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=205a9f0c88a5f5a3d2d6326c2b1d325a)

If your version doesn't support `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, consider to do the conversion in your application language. Since you've tagged your question with `mysqli`, I assume that you are using PHP. Then you can use [`pred_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php):

```
$row['converted_name'] = preg_replace('/[^\\d\\w]/', '', $row['name']);
$row['converted_name'] = strtoupper($row['converted_name']);
```

[rextester demo](https://rextester.com/IZKVD86527)

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION mydbname.regexp_replace does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL you can use a bunch of nested replace operations for this.

```
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE('3''s Automotors', ' ',''),'''','')) val
```

It's a bit nasty because you need a nested REPLACE for each possible character you want to remove, but it works.

Notice you must represent single-quote characters `'` in string constants in MySQL queries by doubling them.  So, `''''` represents the single character `'` as a string constant.